# ftp_connect() does not return a resource id

Tags: php, ftp

Suddenly when I'm doing this on my server:

```
<?php 
$connection = ftp_connect("ftpserver"); // connect to server
print($connection);print("test");die();
?>
```

It does not return a `Resource id #`.

It happens only on a particular server, if I try the same code on another server it will return:

```
Resource id #2test
```

Is it a server configuration? Nothing changed on that server recently. 
It prints just "test", no null or something else. I've tried multiple ftp servers to make sure that the server IP is not banned.

Tried `function_exists('ftp_connect')` and it is.

Update: check /var/log/syslog to see if it is blocked by firewall.

Comment: What exactly do you get instead of `Resource id #`?

Comment: @MartinHieden nothing, it just prints test.

Comment: Enable error reporting.

Comment: @CodeCaster already enabled, nothing.

Comment: Well without any more info we can't say anything about this. Try enabling logging or whatever to find out the actual error. My guess is that this server doesn't support passive connection and expects the client to initiate a data connection by listening on a port and sending the port number to the server, which fails due to privileges or firewall rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`ftp_connect` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php) returns `false`, if the connection fails.

Printing `false` yields nothing (the `false` converts to an empty string).

Use the `var_dump($connection)` to verify.

You will most likely get:

```
bool(false)
```

Meaning that you cannot connect to the "ftpserver".

The `ftp_connect` should issue a warning with details about the connection problem.

Comment: yes, it outputs false. on other servers which connect to the same ftp server successfully (same code) it outputs null.

Comment: If cannot output null, it should output something like "resource(4) of type (FTP Buffer)"

Comment: The connection is most likely blocked by a firewall. Check if you can FTP from command-line from the same server.

Comment: yes, I'll check firewall, if I try from command line any FTP server I get false

Comment: Yes it was rejecting every outbound connection in /var/log/syslog should have checked that first